# ajax reload is making problems with adding events

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have problem with following code. I have a div with id reloadDiv that is refreshing every 3 seconds using ajax. Content of the div is loaded using php, there is more content in this div but I didn't added it here.

Div is reloading normally. The problem is with input type button event with class replyComment, there are multiple buttons with this class here. When I add click event the event is working until first reload, as soon as div reloads event is not working any more.

Does someone know how to solve this problem?

```
<div id="reloadDiv">
     <?php foreach($comments as $c):?>
        <input type="button" value="Reply" class="replyComment" /> 
     <?php endforeach?>
</div>
```

js:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $("#reloadDiv").load(location.href + " #replyComment");
}, 3000);

$('.replyComment').click(function(){
    console.log("smth")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens because content is replaced, and the element with the event doesn't exists anymore, as well the event.

Try this:

```
$('#reloadDiv').on('click', '.replyComment', function() {
```

With that, the event is bound to the parent element and will work no matter how many times the content is recreated.